# Inside a panel , show a pop up message with dark background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, panel

My problem is related to this
[How to show a pop up message with dark background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947504/how-to-show-a-pop-up-message-with-dark-background)

but the main problem is i want to add the fade form and the focus form both inside a panel . I have asked this question in many forums but no one answered . i am using panel to open and close forms but got suggestion to create a user control instead but no one never told me to how to design that user control and how to use that . If any one here has the time here to help me , please do so .

i have a panel in my form and there is form named form1 opened inside a panel . i want to add this fade form over this form1 so that the control of form1 should be partially visible and when this happened , i want to open a focus form of which the link i just shared . Just this i want .

Comment: You're trying to do something fancy that WinForms just wasn't ever intended to do. This is why Microsoft created WPF. It was built from the ground up to do fancy stuff like this. There's a reason no one has answered you. Use the right tool for the job and you'll have better luck. You're also compounding the issue by using a form as a control instead of using a control.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , using a form as a control instead of using a control . So what control should I had to use . I cannot use WPF .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I follow.

> i have a panel in my form

[image: sample panel with three rando buttons]

---

> there is form named form1 opened inside a panel

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    .
    .
    .
    Form1 form1 { get; } = new Form1
    {
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
    };
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        form1.Location = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(panel1.Right - 370, 50));
        form1.Show(this);
    }
}
```

[image: form inside panel]

---

> i want to add this fade form **over** this **form1** so that the **control of form1 should be partially visible** and when this happened

[image: animation]

**Fade Form**

```
class FadeForm : Form
{
    const float TARGET_OPACITY = 0.85F;
    public FadeForm()
    {
        BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 20);
        var linkLabel = new LinkLabel
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
            Text = "https://www.google.com",
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            Height = 50,
        };
        linkLabel.LinkClicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Do something with {linkLabel.Text}");
        };
        Controls.Add(linkLabel);
    }
    public new async void Show(IWin32Window owner)
    {
        base.Show(owner);
        if (owner is Form parent)
        {
            localSubscribeParent();
            localTrackParent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                
            // Animate
            for (float f = 0; f <= TARGET_OPACITY; f += 0.03F)
            {
                Opacity = Math.Pow(f, 2);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01));
                if (!Visible) break; // If form hides during animation.
            }
            void localSubscribeParent()
            {
                parent.Move -= localTrackParent;
                parent.SizeChanged -= localTrackParent;
                parent.Move += localTrackParent;
                parent.SizeChanged += localTrackParent;
            }
            void localTrackParent(object? sender, EventArgs e) =>
                Bounds = parent.RectangleToScreen(parent.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
}
```

---

**Main Form**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        foreach (var button in panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                FadeForm.Hide();
                FadeForm.Show(form1);
                switch (button.Name) 
                {
                    case nameof(button1): FadeForm.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;  break;
                    case nameof(button2): FadeForm.BackColor = Color.LightGreen; break;
                    case nameof(button3): FadeForm.BackColor = Color.LightCoral; break;
                }
            };
        }
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            FadeForm.Dispose();
            form1.Dispose();
        };
    }
    Form1 form1 { get; } = new Form1
    {
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
    };
    FadeForm FadeForm { get; } = new FadeForm();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        form1.Location = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(panel1.Right - 370, 50));
        form1.Show(this);
    }
}
```

---

> i want to open a focus form of which the link i just shared

[image: open link]

My crystal ball gets fuzzy at this point about what you want to do next but hopefully this gives you a starting point.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/fade-form.git)

Comment: @IV Software , just amazing ..