# WinForms: Dark background on parent form upon new child form window

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for something like an active/inactive form where for example: When a child form pops up, the focus is directed on the child form, thus darkening the Parent Form when it's not focused.

I tried the solution by Idle_Mind @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/27305972/5617676 . It worked **perfectly for my friend** but for some reason it partially worked for me (We have the same exact code and program since we're both working on this one system). What happened was when the child form pops up, the Parent form zooms in for about 20% and also a part of the parent form is cut off.

Sample Pictures:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSWmn.jpg) and [After (Child Form popup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHA2z.jpg)

Comment: Try [Draw semi transparent overlay image all over the windows form having some controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4503210/719186)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32242963/17034

Comment: is this about the DPI dependency/independency?

Comment: @LarsTech that one also partially worked, the darkened area is not in lined with the parent form, rather it's not centered. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/NlmU1dJ.jpg -- I also tried to change the this.startposition into CenterScreen (didnt work) then I tried CenterParent (same result).

Comment: @HansPassant I tried your solution at LarsTech's comment. I commented the details above, can you suggest what must I do?